# Git add library outside of project folder?

Tags: git, visual-studio, static-libraries

I have the following project structure:

- MyProgram/

  - .git/
  - MyProgram/

    - File.c
    - File.h
    - MainFile.c
- MyProgram.exe
- MyStaticLibrary/

  - MyStaticLibrary/

    - ImportantFile.c
    - ImportantFile.h

  In **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015**, I linked *MyProgram* with *MyStaticLibrary* so I could use *ImportantFile.c/h* in multiple of my projects. However, when it came to commiting this to GitHub, I discovered that I couldn't find a way to `add` `MyStaticLibrary` to the repo. If I attempt to, it gives the following error:

  `fatal ../MyStaticLibrary is outside repository`

  I don't want to do any merging or manual copy pasting because what if I had 100 libraries? Then you can't just copy paste on every commit. Another option is for me to just not include `MyStaticLibrary` on my repository but then anyone who wishes to compile my code cannot do so.

  What do I do?

Comment: Do you have any local-commit history ? If not you could simply delete the git folder, `init` it in the root folder and push the changes again! :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but `MyStaticLibrary` needs to stay in the location that it's in, as it's used in multiple projects. If I moved it inside a folder specifically for `MyProgram`, then it would 'belong' to `MyProgram`. I have other GitHub projects that need access to `MyStaticLibrary` and it cannot go in multiple folders at once :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward interpretation of that error message is the correct one: you can't add files "above" the repository.

Ideally you would version `MyStaticLibrary/` separately from all the projects that depend on it, and use either a dependency manager or [Git `submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to bring the source into projects that depend on it. If you have 100 libraries that all depend on such a submodule, you would want to write a script to bring them all up-to-date.

---

> I don't want to do any merging or manual copy pasting because what if I had 100 libraries? Then you can't just copy paste on every commit.

This instinct is a good one; Just Say No to manual copy/paste.

> Another option is for me to just not include MyStaticLibrary on my repository but then anyone who wishes to compile my code cannot do so.

Similarly, avoid letting projects require stuff that isn't in the repository or readily available.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing, unless you have already created some history you want to save, would be to just delete the `.git` subdirectory and redo the init in the correct directory.

Presumably you can also do the following if you have git history:

```
$ mv .git ../
$ cd ..
$ git add . --all 
$ git status // => you can see all the files recognized as renamed 100%
$ git commit -m "Moves repo to root directory."
```

Comment: I can't do that because I need `MyStaticLibrary` to be in the same directory as all of my other programming projects. I have multiple separate programs that rely on `MyStaticLibrary` in the same way that `MyProgram` does.

Comment: @Hatefiend That should like impossible. Have you tried creating Alias of `MyStaticFolder` in the project folders ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Like creating a shortcut of a folder in a  folder. for example there will be shortcut of `MyStaticFolder` folder in `MyProgram/` folder. But that would not solve an issue of accessing that folder, i guess but there would actually let you know that this folder `MyProgram/` is referencing some files from `MyStaticFolder`